# Training year transition

Tags: filemaker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71CXL.png)I am hoping that someone can help me with the below problem.

I am trying to create a field in a database to indicate the date that a trainee will move to thier next year of training. They go to next year of training after 52 weeks training. They may have multiple placements during a particular training year.

I have their training  start date (trainee::startdate... their start and end date (traineeplacement::startdate and traineeplacement::enddate) of each job (in a linked table), their percentage of full time (traineeplacement::PercentageFullTime)  and the calculated number of weeks whole time equilavent in the job (traineeplacement::durationweeks).

Through using the cumulative time in a training (traineeplacement::training-duration), in excel I can find the end of the block before using Max statment with an imbedded if statement to find max value less than 52 weeks in cumulative time in training. I cannot seem to do this in filemaker. I would then like to find the next line in the traineeplacement table and from that I can calculate the end of training year date from start of placment date, % of fulltime, and number of weeks neediing to be worked to get to 52 weeks...

The placements are measured in weeks for ease and training runs over a minimum of 4 years, calculated from start and end dates of each placement. The placement dates are a consecutive, but I will only count the product of weeks worked and % of full time (full time =100%, not working (e.g. maternity leave) = 0%). Hope this makes sense and I have included a screen shot of the draft of the database to give you an idea of what I mean.

I hope this makes sense.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpIHG.png)

[Excel spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpIHG.png)
[Excel Spreadsheet Formulae](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nRR0.png)

Comment: It would be easier to understand your question if you included the formula you use in Excel to achieve this. FileMaker also has a Max function, have you tried recreating your formula with this?

Comment: I've added a spreadsheet with the numbers and one with the formula

Comment: Ok, read up on FileMaker's Max function and how it works. It can either work on a related field, a set of non-repeating fields or a set of values from any source. Looks to me that it can do the job as long as you feed it the data needed. Put the Max function inside the conditional.